# Using XPath to get element value with XML package (R)

Tags: r, xml, xpath

Say I have the following XML snippet:

```
<book>
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

How can I get the price value? I've tried variations of this snippet using XPath:

```
library("XML")
price = xpathSApply(doc, '//book/price')
```

but it's not returning `29.99` as I expected.

Comment: any reason to use XML over xml2?

Comment: Is that the whole XML or snippet? If latter, you may be ignoring default namespaces which can return no value by your XPath. Try adding a return object too: `xpathSApply(doc, "//book/price", xmlValue)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read with `read_xml`

```
library(xml2)
dat <- read_xml("doc1.xml")
as.numeric(xml_text(xml_find_all(dat, "price")))
[1] 29.99
```